# replace old function with new with arguments

Tags: javascript, function, replace

I have object with variables and functions ... and definition of new "function2"

```
var object = {
    x: 11,
    y: 22,
    getX: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
};

var function2 = function(value) {
    return value;    
};
```

I want to replace definition of old getX function:

```
object.getX = function2(arg);
```

but this code is not replacing function, but setting new value

how to make it ?

I want value "15" when I call object.getX(15) .... value "aa" when I call object.getX("aa")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `bind(context,arguments..)` for this purpose,

```
object.getX = function2.bind(object, arg);
```

And if you just want to replace the `function` without setting any context(`this`),

Then you can do it simply by.

```
object.getX = function2;
```

Your full code would be,

```
var object = {
    x: 11,
    y: 22,
    getX: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
};

var function2 = function(value) { return value; };
object.getX = function2.bind(object);

console.log(object.getX("aa")); //"aa"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply like

```
object.getX = function2;
```